# How to apply Microsoft office 365 developer licence to multiple users

Tags: azure, office365, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm exploring office 365 graph API's. I have created the office 365 developer account using admin@saasdev.onmicrosoft.com and tried out the following steps successfully:
1. Registered a app
2. Retrieved the access_token to send out an test email to admin@saasdev.onmicrosoft.com

Now I have created another user called 'user@saasdev.onmicrosoft.com' using 'admin@saasdev.onmicrosoft.com' and tried my registered app to send-out a test email from user@saasdev.onmicrosoft.com. But graph api throws error as "The requested user 'admin@saasdev.onmicrosoft.com' is invalid."

Then I have tried to assign the 'Microsoft office 365 developer license' to admin@saasdev.onmicrosoft.com, but got an error message in Office 365 admin centre preview as 'This trial subscription doesn't have any licenses available. Buy subscription to assign license'.

Is that not possible to assign already existing 'Microsoft office 365 developer license' to multiple users? Do I need to pay and buy another license and apply that to another user (atleast at the developer's point of view)?

Answer (score 1):

The trial subscription of Office 365 only enable you test with the account you register. There is no any licenses available for other users. If you want to assign the licenses for other account, you need to buy subscription.

You can also refer to assign licenses manually like figure below and buy the subscription from the [portal](https://portal.office.com/AdminPortal/Home?switchtomoderndefault=true#/homepage):
[image]